# TinyMCE mutate src for images inserting by custom plugin

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I've implemented my own plugin that inserts a generated math formula. Src for this image are assigned as a relative path and looks like:

`<img src="/api/rendermath?formula=y^x2">`

Also I used it together with `react-tinymce` library. But when I asked the value from textarea it returned me a mutated image src:

`<img src="../api/rendermath?formula=y^x2">`

When this returned value was rendering into this textarea again it mutated this images again:

`<img src="api/rendermath?formula=y^x2">`

Of course, nothing work. Could you help me to fix it? 
P.s. I would like to avoid hard-coding the current host-name in src of image

Answer (score 0):

I don't see TinyMCE doing that by default:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Ulgaab/1

I am guessing that either you have some other configuration setting that is impacting the URLs or you have some other code processing things?